# How are probabilities combined in the game hopping proof technique?

Tags: provable-security, semantic-security, probability, game

I'm currently studying a paper (*[Sequences of Games: A Tool for Taming Complexity in Security Proofs](https://www.shoup.net/papers/games.pdf)*) on proving semantic security using the Game Hopping technique by Victor Shoup.

On pages 9-11, he is using a sequence of three games, $Game 1$, $Game 2$, and $Game 3$ to deduct the semantic security of Hashed [ElGamal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ElGamal_encryption) to [DDH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decisional_Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_assumption) and entropy smoothing assumptions. How does he combine the three probabilities equations, namely $(1
)$, $(2)$, $(3)$ to derive the last one, $|Pr[S_0]-1/2| \le ε_{ddh} + ε_{es}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The three equations you reference are (we'll just take them as truth - their proof can be found in the PDF):

$$
\begin{align}
|Pr[S_0] - Pr[S_1]| & = \epsilon_{\text{ddh}} & \text{ (1)} \\
|Pr[S_1] - Pr[S_2]| & = \epsilon_{\text{es}} & \text{ (2)} \\
Pr[S_2] & = \frac{1}{2} & \text{ (3)} \\
\end{align}
$$

Then:
$$
\begin{align}
\epsilon_{\text{ddh}} + \epsilon_{\text{es}} & = |Pr[S_0] - Pr[S_1]| + |Pr[S_1] - Pr[S_2]| & \text{(1) + (2)} \\
& \geq  |Pr[S_0] - Pr[S_1] + Pr[S_1] - Pr[S_2]| & \text{Triangle inequality} \\
& = |Pr[S_0] - Pr[S_2]| \\
& = \left|Pr[S_0] - \frac{1}{2}\right| & \text{(3)}
\end{align}
$$